# How to use JQuery to open a tabbed modal automatically with a particular tab open

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I am submitting data from a form embedded inside a tabbed bootstrap modal to a controller method in laravel 5.2.

Each of the tabs have their different forms and I am required to display validation errors at the top of the form for each tab. This is how I did it: At the top of each form in all the tabs, I have added the validation errors display code. If there is an error with the form, the error would be displayed at the top of the form but I would not be able to see it. Now I did some search and was able to automatically re-open the modal in case there was an error in filling the form using this piece of code in my view:

```
@if ($errors->all())
    $('#modal').modal('show');
@endif
```

But this only opens the modal to the default tab. I want to be able to open the modal to the tab with the form the user was filling and If possible i would like to do this with JQuery. Is it possible?

My modal looks something like this:

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#TaskListDialog" role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal">Launch modal</a>

<div id="TaskListDialog" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="windowTitleLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <h3>Modal Heading</h3>
           </div>

           <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="tabbable">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                             //space for another form here
                         </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                        //display validation error here
                            <form action="{{ route('someroute/') }}">
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"> <br>
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control"> <br>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As seen on the code, the tabs are `section 1` and `section 2`.

Once more my question is, How do I open the modal with `section 2` active instead of  the default `section 1`? Or is there a better way of doing the whole stuff?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please let know if my solution has worked for you? Its always good to know the feedback :)

Comment: @Prakash I didn't try yours, I found a way before you answered. Thanks anyway for your own idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can activate any section of `nav` you want with below code

```
 $('.nav-tabs a[href="#id_of_the_nav"]').tab('show');
```

So in your case if you want to activate the `Section 2` just replace the `id_of_the_nav` with `tab2`

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/Prakash_Thete/s6jjmdc4/1/

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i found a way. I used a click `trigger` in jquery.

```
<script>
    $('#tab_id').trigger('click');
</script>
```

This is equivalent to actually clicking on the tab.